# Draw line connector for Raphael shapes

Tags: jquery, raphael, graphael

I am drawing chart similar to graffle (http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html). however i don't want curved connector lines, instead want straight lines (with some curve at the intersection) as shown in the below pic (got from one of the other post but could not get solution there). Since my diagram can be complex with many to many relationship, so lines connector can cut through many lines, so lines should be distinguishable enough to show the neat connection. here is my sample code. Can someone suggest me approach for getting it done.

```
  connections = [];
  var shapes = new Array();
  var texts = new Array();
  var moreinfo=new Array();
  var kx=20,ky=50;
  var RecWidth=80;
  var RecHeight=40;
  var RecRadius=5;

for (var i=0; i<= 5; i++) {
    shapes[i]=r.rect(kx, ky, RecWidth, RecHeight,RecRadius);
    texts[i]=r.text(kx + 35, ky + 10, "SlsMktGst"+i );
    moreinfo[i]=r.text(kx + 35, ky + 30, "More" );
    moreinfo[i].id="more"+i;
    shapes[i].id="keylist"+i ;
    shapes[i].attr({fill: '#000080', stroke: '#000080', "fill-opacity": 0, "stroke-width": 2, cursor: "move"});
    texts[i].attr({fill: '#0000A0', stroke: "none", "font-size": 12,"font-weight":"bold", cursor: "move"});
    moreinfo[i].attr({fill: '#0000A0', stroke: "none", "font-weight":"bold", cursor: "move"});

     kx=kx+125;
     ky=ky+50;
};
```

//draw connection lines with arrow used http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

```
for (var jj=0; jj<=shapes.length-1; jj++) {

    if(jj != shapes.length-1){
        connections.push(r.connection(shapes[jj], shapes[jj+1], "#000", "#fff","Y"));
    };
};
```

**Current result:**
    [image: Current result from above code]

---

Expected result
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In you Raphael connection method use change your path variable from

```
var path = ["M", x1.toFixed(3), y1.toFixed(3), "C", x2, y2, x3, y3, x4.toFixed(3), y4.toFixed(3)].join(",");
```

to this

```
var path = ["M", x1.toFixed(3), y1.toFixed(3), "L", x2, y2, x3, y3, x4.toFixed(3), y4.toFixed(3)].join(",");
```

The difference is that "C" has been changed to "L" in the path.

According to [raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path)

- C = Curved Line
- L = Straight Line

Thanks